# How to create readonly users in amazon mysql RDS using ansible

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, ansible

I want to create a read only user in a number of RDS instances inside a VPC. The basic way of doing it is:

> 1. mysql -h "rds_endpoint" -u "admin_user" -p
> 2. GRANT SELECT on *.* to 'eng_ro'@'jump_box_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
> 3. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

I use a jumpbox (public facing ip) to login the VPC. I wrote a playbook like :

```
---
- name: Connect  to the mysql db as root
  mysql_user:
     login_user: root
     login_password: temp+1234
     host: {{ item }}
  with_items:
     - rds_endpoint1
     - rds_endpoint2

- name: Create smeng_ro user for all databases
  mysql_user:
     login_user: root
     login_password: temp+1234
     host: {{ item }}
     name: smeng_ro
     password: engronly
     priv: *.*,GRANT
     state: present
  with_items:
     - rds_endpoint1
     - rds_endpoint2
```

But it's not doing what I want, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, your first task isn't actually doing anything so you can remove it.

As for creating a user with certain permissions you've basically covered that in your second task however the privileges you are giving simply give the [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) permission to the user on all databases. Although on closer inspection you are using a comma instead of a colon between what databases to select (`*.*`) and the actual permissions given (`GRANT`) .

If instead you would like to just give [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) on all the databases you can replace that line with `priv: *.*:SELECT`. The format for the `priv` attribute is given as `db.table:priv1,priv2` in the [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_user_module.html).

So your task should just look like this:

```
- name: Create smeng_ro user for all databases
  mysql_user:
     login_user: root
     login_password: temp+1234
     host: {{ item }}
     name: smeng_ro
     password: engronly
     priv: *.*:SELECT
     state: present
  with_items:
     - rds_endpoint1
     - rds_endpoint2
```

Comment: This was useful for me.  However I had to change host to login_host for the rds endpoints, and host to either '%' or the remote host I'm connecting from.  Also had to add quotes around priv like so '\*.\*:SELECT'